# "Features" link missing on TFS backlog page for particular user

Tags: tfs

I've just set up a new project in TFS2013 using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3" template.  If I browse to the team backlog page I can see features and backlog items:

[image: features and backlog items are both visible]

Unfortunately our product owner can only see the backlog items - features are missing from the page:

[image]

We have eliminated browser differences and proved that it's linked to the particular user account.

Is this likely to be due to a licensing difference between my account (and the accounts of other members of my team) and our product owner?  From the screenshot I've been sent, I can see that the product owner is also unable to see the "Test" menu item.

As far as I can tell from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159364.aspx) docs, the "no license" stakeholder should have permissions to view Features.

Is this a TFS client license issue?  Is there a way I can tell what sort of TFS license a user has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You product owner is likely in the Basic licence group
.

If you go to the TFS homepage and click the cog in the top right you will open the admin page. If you then select "Control Panel" on the top right you will get the server level controls.

There is a licensing tab here with defaults and a description of what you get for each one.

Note: Your PO should be in Advanced..but that also requires a licence...